# Python: Multistart optimization using parallel programming

Tags: optimization, matlab, python, parallel-computing

[I previously asked my question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505583/python-multisearch-optimization-using-parallel-programming) but this site may be more appropriate]

In Matlab, I am currently using the [MultiStart](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/multistart-class.html) as an optimization algo in a parallel setup for a computer cluster. For example, this is my Matlab code:

```
opts = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp','Use Parallel','Always'); %The options for the algo. The key here is the Use Parallel 
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','objective',...
 @(x) x.^2 + 4*sin(5*x),'x0',3,'lb',-5,'ub',5,'options',opts); %x is the variable I wish to min/max
ms = MultiStart;
[x,f] = run(ms,problem,20) %20 stands for the number of initial random variables
```

This code works very well when I submit a batch job on the cluster for X processors.
I am looking online for a similar algo that I could implement in parallel using Python and I am bit loss. Any similar algo is available for Python?

**UPDATE**
As for my cluster requirements, multithreading is not acceptable. Usually I use `mpi4py`.

Comment: Have you looked at [Coopr](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr) (which includes Pyomo)?

Comment: Interesting ... not so trival to see how to implement a MultiSearch from their help guide but I will look into this more. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can tell, MultiStart is not an optimization algorithm per se, but a framework that runs a given optimization algorithm (in your code, SQP via `fmincon`) in parallel for a set of random starting points (i.e., a separate, independent, instance of `fmincon` for each starting point).  Since the instances do not need to communicate at all, this does not require MPI (the technical term is "embarrassingly parallel"), so you can use any job server to launch the instances, each on a separate node.

Since Python is (if you so choose) much more low-level than Matlab, you can implement this yourself rather easily: Pick an implementation of a minimization algorithm (the closest thing to `fmincon` would be SciPy's [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)) and wrap it in a [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) Pool; the module [`joblib`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) seems to provide a convenient wrapper for this. If you run this on a cluster, you could try [`dispy`](http://dispy.sourceforge.net).

On a higher level, Coopr (an optimization modeling framework similar to AMPL) provides capabilities for [Solving Multiple Instances in Parallel](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/coopr/CooprGettingStarted.html#_solving_multiple_instances_in_parallel).

Comment: yes you are absolutely right with your first point about MultiSearch not being an optimizaiton algo per se. Putting parallel prog. aside, can `scipy.optimize.minimize` be set to start with random starting points? Also, correct me if I am wrong, but multiprocessing (I was told) will not work on cluster and I usually use `mpi4py` to parallel job on a cluster. Is Coopr my only alternative to run `scipy.optimize.minimize` parallel on a cluster?

Comment: What I have in mind is if `scipy.optimize.minimize` can take multiple random starting values like in Matlab's Multisearch, then I augment the performance with `mpi4py` ... no idea if this is feasible.

Comment: No, `minimize` takes only a single starting point. What you would do is write a loop, where in each iteration you select a random starting point and run a new instance of `minimize` on that and collect the results. Then you only need a framework that allows you to execute the loop in parallel. If `multithreading` is not acceptable, simply replace it with a more suitable job server for Python. The best idea is to ask your cluster admin what they support.